# How to set a global Place holder colour for a UITextField for the whole app in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextfield, appdelegate

I am creating a app in which i use several `UITextfield`'s. I know how to change the `placeholder` colour of a single text field.

`textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()])`.

But i want to change the placeholder colour of all the `UITextField`s in the whole app. My app has more than 50 `UIViewControllers` and more than 25 of them has textFields(2 to 22 per screen). I want a code that can be used globally in one place so that i don't need to go to every view controller and change it manually.

If you have any other alternatives to make the job done please let me know.

I am using `xcode 7.1.1` `swift 2.0`

Update:
For default the Placeholder colour is set to light grey colour. Is there any way for us to tweak that default behaviour and change it to any other colour?

How can we access this default code and change it?

Comment: see this it helps you https://www.natashatherobot.com/using-swift-extensions/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I saw the link but i don't know how it could be helpful in my code. Could you be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the extension method

```
extension String {

func toAttributedString(font font:UIFont!, kerning: CGFloat!, color:UIColor!) -> NSAttributedString {
    return NSAttributedString(string: self as String, font: font, kerning: kerning, color: color)!
}
}

extension NSAttributedString {

convenience init?(string text:String, font:UIFont!, kerning: CGFloat!, color:UIColor!) {
    self.init(string: text, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName:kerning, NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color])
}
}
```

Example usage

```
/ Example Usage
var testString: String = "Hi Kautham"

var testAttributedString: NSAttributedString = testString.toAttributedString(font: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(20), kerning: 2.0, color: UIColor.whiteColor())


let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 20))

label.attributedText = testAttributedString
 self.view.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is really helpful.

Comment: @KauthamMurugan - happy to hear bro, it works bz I m not tested this

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Macro with your NSAttributedString.

Give that Attributed string to all textfields wherever you want.

So that when you change in Macro, will reflect in all places..

Check out the following.

```
let CommonTextFieldAttr : NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()]
```

And Use it in Textfield properties.

```
textField?.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "sdfa",attributes: CommonTextFieldAttr as? [String : AnyObject])
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: question is related to swift , can you customize your answer

Comment: @Balaji Thanks for your interest.But i know this method already. The problem is, To set the new attribute i must use the second line of your code in all the view controllers for each and every text field which i hate to do. I have several text fields in one view controller upto 22 max.